# PHP - per class configuration manager and inheritance

Tags: php, dependency-injection, multiple-inheritance

I have a class `Injector` whichs uses `get_class($this)` to get the class using Injector, to load some data in the class from db or file ... it works great with simple inheritance like `class User extends Injector`.

The problem is: if a class `SpecialUser` extends `User`, `get_class` returns only `SpecialUser` and `User` will not filled with needed data. Is there a better solution then loop trouth the classes with get_parent_class()?

thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! please read [*this*](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
$names = array();

if ($this instanceof Injector) {
    $class = get_class($this);

    do {
        $names[] = $class;
        $class = get_parent_class($class);
    } while ($class !== 'Injector');
}
```

[Here's an example of its usage](http://codepad.org/kBb8RzNh).